# Implementation of Poll Mechanism in Char Device Driver

Tags: select, module, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Hello Dear participants of stackoverflow,

I'm new to kernel space development and still in the beginning of the road.
I developed a basic char device driver that can read open close etc . But couldn't find a proper source and how to tutorial for Poll/select mechanism sample.

I've written the sample code for poll function below:

```
static unsigned int dev_poll(struct file * file, poll_table *wait)
```

{

```
poll_wait(file,&dev_wait,wait);
if (size_of_message > 0 ){
    printk(KERN_INFO "size_of_message > 0 returning POLLIN | POLLRDNORM\n");
    return POLLIN | POLLRDNORM;
}
else {
    printk(KERN_INFO "dev_poll return 0\n");
    return 0;
}
```

}

It works fine but couldn't undestand a few things.

When I call select from user space program as

```
    struct timeval time  = {5,0 } ;
select(fd + 1 , &readfs,NULL,NULL,&time);
```

the dev_poll function in driver called once and return zero or POLLIN in order to buffer size . And then never called again. In user space , after 5 seconds the program continue if dev_poll returned 0. 
What I couldn't understand is here , How the driver code will decide and let user space program if there is something in buffer that is readable withing this 5 seconds , if it's called once and returned immediately.

Is there anyway in kernel module to gather information of timeval parameter that comes from userspace ?

Thank you from now on.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Call `poll_wait()` actually places some *wait* object into a waitqueue, specified as a second parameter. When wait object is fired (via waitqueue's `wake_up` or similar function), the poll function is evaluated again.

Kernel driver needn't to bother about timeouts: when time is out, the wait object will be removed from the waitqueue automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Then how I  should handle the situations to let the kernel when I have data available withing the timeout ?

As example , user space call select with 5 secs timeout. 
In the beginning  of the select I have no data in device. Then I have the data withing 2 seconds. So I want to wake up the user space program. How I can implement this ?

Comment: As written in the answer, when queue becomes non-empty you need to call `wake_up` for the waitqueue which you are using for `poll`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear curious people like me about poll . I came up with a solution.

From another topic on stackowerflow a guy said that the poll_function is called multiple times if kernel need to last situation. So basically I implement that code .

when poll called call wait_poll(wait_queue_head);
when device have buffered data(this is usually in driver write function).
call wake_up macro with wait_queue_head paramater.
So after this step poll function of driver is called again .
So here you can return whatever you want to return. In this case POLLIN | POLLRDNORM..

Here is my sample code for write and poll in the driver.

```
    static unsigned int dev_poll(struct file * file, poll_table *wait)
{
    static int dev_poll_called_count = 0 ;
    dev_poll_called_count ++;
    poll_wait(file,&dev_wait,wait);
    read_wait_queue_length++;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside dev_poll called time is : %d read_wait_queue_length %d\n",dev_poll_called_count,read_wait_queue_length);

    printk(KERN_INFO "After poll_wait wake_up called\n");
    if (size_of_message > 0 ){
        printk(KERN_INFO "size_of_message > 0 returning POLLIN | POLLRDNORM\n");
        return POLLIN | POLLRDNORM;
    }
    else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "dev_poll return 0\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

    static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *filep, const char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside write \n");;
    int ret;    
    ret = copy_from_user(message, buffer, len);
    size_of_message = len ;
    printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Received %zu characters from the user\n", size_of_message);
    if (ret)
        return -EFAULT;
    message[len] = '\0';
    printk(KERN_INFO "gelen string %s", message);
    if (read_wait_queue_length)
    {
        wake_up(&dev_wait);
        read_wait_queue_length = 0;
    }
    return len;   

}
```